# Persistant Taskbar in Android

Tags: android

I want to have a persistant taskbar like the status bar of Android. I dont want  it to load with individual activity. i want that taskbar to remain persistant for all activities that too at the bottom of the screen.*(Not on top of screen where status bar is present.)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Rohan you need to modify the firmware....Also CommonsWare can you elaborate on your comment to modify the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible from the Android SDK. It should be possible by modifying the firmware.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how i can modify the firmware? can you suggest some turorial since i haven't worked on firmware yet..

Comment: @Rohan K: There isn't a "tutorial". If you new to phone firmware, Android is not the place to start.

Comment: I have the Android OS source code.As per my knowledge the Status Bar must be an OS level application.  Can you please tell me where should i look for the notification manager application (Which folder it must be present). I'm thinking of modifying the OS so that i could bring the status bar at bottom of activity. Thank you for your help.