# Android Activity with 2 status bar?

Tags: android

Can i create an activity with 2 status bar?

Can i put the status bar at the bottom of Activity?

Comment: and a possible duplicated post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725742/persistant-taskbar-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status bar is not part of the Activity. Of course, you can design your Activity UI to have 2 bars with all kinds of info, but I guess that is not what you mean?

Putting THE status bar (with the battery level, notifications etc.) on a different place seems rather hardcoded in the window manager/layouter to me and I think you cannot change this from within an Activity.